# Cannot play MP4 video in Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, html5-video, mp4

I have 2 days dealing with a weird issue about a mp4 video in angular 7. For some reason the MP4 video simply does not play.

This is my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="instructions" class="angled-img pull-left">
        <video allow="autoplay" width="350px" height="195px" class="img" controls
          poster='{{gameInfo.clip.preview}}'>
          <source src="{{gameInfo.clip.clip}}" type='video/mp4' />
        </video>
      </div>
```

TS:

```
public gameInformation(id: number): void {
this.gameService.getGame(id).subscribe(res => {
  this.gameInfo = res;
  console.log(res);
  this.loader = false;
}, error => {
  console.error(error);
  this.loader = false;
});
}
```

I am not sure why this is happening. Can somebody help me out? What I am doing wrong.
I am using ngx-bootstrap for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to explicitly call play method once you get the response. document.getElementById('video').play()

Comment: Property 'play' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.ts(2339)

Comment: It also seems that the controls are disabled.

Comment: Which browsers did you try? Also,  instead of  allow="autoplay"   just  try using  autoplay  by its self.

Comment: I am using Chrome and Mozilla, however for some reason, if I add the URL properly in the HTML it works but if I use the JSON response the issue appears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am able to play video in the promise. Use these attributes in the Video tag  **"muted"** and **"autoplay"**.

Also I have created stackblitz example where I am calling a fake http call and I am trying to play sample video. Please use **ngIf="gameInfo"** in your video tag to make sure your response data is available before rendering your video. Also you can wrap the video play inside setTimeout to make sure video tag is rendered in the page.

Here is the stackblitz working example.

[Play Video using angular](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tfrvpt)

**app.component.html**

```html
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>

<div id="instructions" class="angled-img pull-left">
        <video muted autoplay  *ngIf="videoData" id="video1"  width="350px" height="195px" class="img" controls
         >
          <source src="{{videoData.url}}" type='video/mp4' />
        </video>
      </div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { VideoService } from './video.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  name = 'Angular';
  videoData: any = {};

  constructor(private videoService: VideoService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.videoService.getVideo().subscribe(data => {
        this.videoData = data;
        this.videoData.url = 'https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4';
        setTimeout(() => {
            document.getElementById('video1').play();
        }, 1000);
    }, (error) => {
        this.videoData.url = 'https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4';
        setTimeout(() => {
  document.getElementById('video1').play();
        }, 1000);
      
      console.log('error', error)
    })
  }
}
```

**video.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'

@Injectable()
export class VideoService {
   private httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json'
    })
  };

  url: string;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
    this.url = 'http://my-json-server.typicode.com/kodecrash/Javascript/video/1';
  }

  getVideo() {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.url, this.httpOptions)
    .pipe(map( (data: any) => {
      // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
      return data;
    }));
  }

}
```

Comment: Your blitz works for some reason, but the code in angular doesn't work because of the 
`.play();` not being a method. Even in your blitz the error is displayed

Comment: If there is an error in play method it should be shown in console. Stackblitz has in built linting features to show these kind of errors. You can ignore that. .play() is built in javaScript method for video tag.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that chrome has disabled autoplay of videos containing sound, so, you need to use muted and autoplay attributes. Still, it is possible that video does not autoplay because you need to write muted before autoplay to make the autoplay work but during compilation, angular arranges attributes in alphabetical order. So, 1 good solution I found was:

```
<video autoplay onloadedmetadata="this.muted = true" oncanplay="this.play()">
    <source [src]="gameinfo.clip.clip" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

This way the video will autoplay in angular without changing anything in the typescript file.

Comment: This actually worked for me. Obviously getting rid of the syntax mistake with the [src]= first and actually closing the quotes..

Comment: Wow this actually worked! How do you know that chrome has disabled autoplay? I found a [chrome developer blog post about autoplay policy](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/), but am wondering if you have any other resources you could point me to. Thank you!